# splitting comma separated data in python

Tags: python, split, mapreduce, mrjob

**SOLVED**

solution at the end of the question....

I'm making a map reduce code using MRjob in python and i have a CSV dataset following are few rows from the dataset.

**column headings**

Year    Length  Title   Genre   Actor   Actress Director    Popularity  Awards  *Image

**Row 1**

1990,111,Tie Me Up! Tie Me Down!,Comedy,"Banderas, Antonio","Abril, Victoria","Almodóvar, Pedro",68,No,"NicholasCage.png,,"

**Row 2**

1991,113,High Heels,Comedy,"Bosé, Miguel","Abril, Victoria","Almodóvar, Pedro",68,No,"NicholasCage.png,,"

now in mapper I am splitting on basis of comma separation but some columns like movie name genre director actor or actress also have ', ' in them a comma with a space which is causing a problem as I am new to map reduce I'm unable to identify how can i split them into perfectly splitted columns

**code for finding total number of movies of each genre. Considering only the movies released after 1970 and have a length greater than 75 minutes.**

```
class MovieGenreCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        movie = line.split(',')
        year = int(movie[0])
        length = int(movie[1])
        genre = movie[2]
        if year > 1970 and length > 75:
            yield genre, 1
    
    def combiner(self, genre, counts):
        yield genre, sum(counts)
    
    def reducer(self, genre, counts):
        yield genre, sum(counts)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MovieGenreCount.run()
```

**SOLUTION**

```
import csv

class MovieGenreCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        row = list(csv.reader([line]))[0]
        year, length, title, genre, actor, actress, director, popularity, awards, image = row
        if year and length:
            year = int(year)
            length = int(length)
            if year > 1970 and length > 75:
                yield genre, 1
    
    def combiner(self, genre, counts):
        yield genre, sum(counts)
    
    def reducer(self, genre, counts):
        yield genre, sum(counts)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MovieGenreCount.run()
```

Comment: Why not use the `csv` module?

Comment: A generator function should have a loop.

Comment: @Barmar im not particularly familiar with csv module but i did try it this way `row = list(csv.reader([line]))[0]
        year, length, title, genre, actor, actress, director, popularity, awards, image = row` but it converts all values to string and even when i tried typecasting on year and length using int() the code is giving following error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: That means you have an empty string in that field.

Comment: @Barmar there are empty values in length but how should i handle them?

Comment: Check if it's empty and set the variable to `0`.

Comment: @Barmar would putting a simple if check be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, or use `try/except`

Comment: @it worked rather than putting 0's i only implied the check a didn't changed or inserted any values